# Why are the top application indicators (top bar icons) appearing black and white in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, top-bar

[image: Screenshot of top panel]

Why are these app indicators appearing in black and white color? Not sure if this was the case while using Ubuntu 18.04. Can something be done to make the app indicators use their original default icon color.

[image: Screenshot of Appearance section of Tweaks]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because they are configured to show as symbolic and symbolic Icons are generally in light gray or whatever we see in actual from the gnome-shell theme currently used.

So navigate to the gnome-shell theme you are using and try to locate "symbolic".

For example the left part on top bar:

```css
#panel .panel-button .app-menu-icon {
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  -st-icon-style: symbolic;
}
```

change the `-st-icon-style: regular;`

Another example:

```css
.aggregate-menu {
  min-width: 21em;
}

.aggregate-menu .popup-menu-icon {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 4px;
  -st-icon-style: regular;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

---

In the default installation of Ubuntu 20.04, the shell theme is from the gresource file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` which can not be edited easily.

Hence the workaround is to create a custom theme in home directory.

**Required:** User Themes  [gnome-shell-extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/)  installed and enabled

Install required directory's and `gnome-shll.css` file with below command, Change the name "MyCustomTheme" in below command to your wish.

```
install -D /dev/null ~/.themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
```

now open the file `gnome-shell.css` with below command

```
gedit ~/.themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
```

paste the below content in the opened `gnome-shell.css` file

```css
#panel .panel-button .app-menu-icon {
  -st-icon-style: regular;
}
```

save the file & close.

Now open gnome-tweaks and choose this newly created shell-theme "MyCustomTheme".

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]