# Top Panel icons+text Ubuntu 20.04 have become extremely small

Tags: 20.04

The question says it all. From yesterday, my top panel icons and text have become very small. Not sure what has happened. I am sharing a screenshot.  Let me know if this can be corrected. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't know. I have never bothered about it. How to check?

Comment: I own a laptop.

Comment: Done. https://imgur.com/a/3FA4M7O :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1269090/739431

Comment: Yes. Very very sudden. Today only. See this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267616/why-are-the-top-application-indicators-top-bar-icons-appearing-black-and-white  See the top panels there. Those fonts look bigger.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1268993/739431

Comment: I guess some system update might be the reason.. And may be its a bug which may be rectified in next update if the developers notice this issue..

Comment: Open `Tweaks` (gnome-tweaks) and show me the **Appearance** and **Fonts** tabs. Also edit your question with the output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. It is back to it's normal shape now, after i did the following : Universal access Large Text off and then again Large Text On. Then the fonts came back to their regular size.

Comment: Where did you find "Universal access Large Text"?

Comment: @pomsky : I don't think that will serve as an answer. Because the moment i restart my computer the same issue pops up again. So i will refrain from adding that as an answer,.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 interface font too small after restart, even with high scaling factor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact) There, you will find some workarounds and the link of the bug opened in launchpad (there is a regression in libmutter package)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes it, but I found a solution.

I went into Gnome Tweaks panel (installed from Ubuntu Software) and changed the Font Size under Fonts to 1.01 and back to 1.00.  That fixed it.

If you aren't using Gnome Tweaks, you may be able to do it in Settings as well, but that worked for me.